# (Jasper Report) Multiple compile jrxml file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I created Invoice with jasper reports and it has some subreport, when I try to compile the jrxml file I get some errors, after doing some analysis i found this error due to multiple compilations.

Here's my code :

```
jasperCompileManager = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
jRXmlLoader = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
JRLoader = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader");
    
subjasperCompileManager = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager");
subjRXmlLoader = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader");
subJRLoader = getLibraryLoader.create("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader");

xmlBuffer = getLibraryLoader.create("java.lang.String").init(stringFile).getBytes();
subXmlBuffer = getLibraryLoader.create("java.lang.String").init(substringFile).getBytes();
xmlInputStream = getLibraryLoader.create("java.io.ByteArrayInputStream").init(xmlBuffer);
subxmlInputStream = getLibraryLoader.create("java.io.ByteArrayInputStream").init(subxmlBuffer);

jasperDesign = jRXmlLoader.load(xmlInputStream);
subjasperDesign = jRXmlLoader.load(subxmlInputStream);

jasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
subjasReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(subjasperDesign);
```

while doing `JasperCompileManager.compileReport` for the second time some errors occurred.

is there any alternative to compiling multiple jrxml files at the same time?

Thanks